# Which MySQL Join query is preferable for this situation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables ..TableA and TableB

in TableA.. I have 5 fields.. ( Empty ) (only structure having Autoincrement-ID field)

in TableB ..I have 7 Fields ( Full ..1 million Recs.)

TableA is Empty .. i want to add a complete column from TableB ..

i.e the **field'ID' in the TableB** shud be inserted inside the the **field'Value' in the TableA.**.

i.e complete **column'ID' from TableB** shud be copied/inserted inside the **TableA as column'Value'**

There is no match case here so i cannot use WHERE clause...

What exactly shud i use outerjoin or innerjoin or full join..

Pls advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TableA(value) SELECT id FROM TableB
```

Comment: This query worked..but but suppose i need one more field i.e 'name' from TableB into the 'name' into the TableA..then can i do this TableA(value,name) SELECT id,name from TableB;